# Why doesn't std::istream_iterator< std::string_view > compile?

Tags: c++, libstdc++, string-view, istream-iterator

Why can't GCC and Clang compile the code snippet below ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/KoPbEf8Pr))? I want to return a vector of `std::string_view`s but apparently there is no way of extracting `string_view`s from the `stringstream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>


[[ nodiscard ]] std::vector< std::string_view >
tokenize( const std::string_view inputStr, const size_t expectedTokenCount )
{
    std::vector< std::string_view > foundTokens { };

    if ( inputStr.empty( ) ) [[ unlikely ]]
    {
        return foundTokens;
    }

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << inputStr;

    foundTokens.reserve( expectedTokenCount );

    std::copy( std::istream_iterator< std::string_view >{ ss }, // does not compile
               std::istream_iterator< std::string_view >{ },
               std::back_inserter( foundTokens ) );

    return foundTokens;
}

int main( )
{
    using std::string_view_literals::operator""sv;
    constexpr auto text { "Today is a nice day."sv };

    const auto tokens { tokenize( text, 4 ) };

    std::cout << tokens.size( ) << '\n';
    std::ranges::copy( tokens, std::ostream_iterator< std::string_view >{ std::cout, "\n" } );
}
```

Note that replacing select instances of `string_view` with `string` lets the code compile.

Comment: Who _owns_ the memory pointed at by `string_view`?

Comment: @tkausl The underlying buffer of the `string_view` object being passed to `tokenize` is managed by the call site (in this case, it's the `main` function).

Comment: I'm talking about the `string_view`s you store in your vector.

Comment: @tkausl Aha yeah that's fair. I'll fix it. But my question still remains, why doesn't that iterator thing compile with `string_view` as its template argument?

Comment: `std::string_view` is fancy form of const reference, so problem is same as stream iterator to const reference.

Comment: @MarekR Yes, it would be good if more people understood that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there is no operator `>>` on `std::stringstream` and `std::string_view` (and `std::istream_iterator` requires this operator).

As [@tkausl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72827897/why-doest-stdistream-iterator-stdstring-view-compile#comment128634685_72827897) points out in the comments, it's not possible for `>>` to work on `std::string_view` because it's not clear who would own the memory pointed to by the `std::string_view`.

In the case of your program, `ss << inputStr` copies the characters from `inputStr` into `ss`, and when `ss` goes out of scope its memory would be freed.

---

Here is a possible implementation that uses C++20's [std::ranges::views::split](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/split_view) instead of `std::stringstream`. It only supports a single space as the delimiter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>


[[ nodiscard ]] std::vector< std::string_view >
tokenize( const std::string_view inputStr, const size_t expectedTokenCount )
{
    constexpr std::string_view delim { " " };

    std::vector< std::string_view > foundTokens { };

    if ( inputStr.empty( ) ) [[ unlikely ]]
    {
        return foundTokens;
    }

    foundTokens.reserve( expectedTokenCount );
    for ( const auto token : std::views::split( inputStr, delim ) )
    {
        foundTokens.emplace_back( token.begin( ), token.end( ) );
    }

    return foundTokens;
}

int main( )
{
    using std::string_view_literals::operator""sv;
    constexpr auto text { "Today is a nice day."sv };

    const auto tokens { tokenize( text, 4 ) };

    std::cout << tokens.size( ) << '\n';
    std::ranges::copy( tokens, std::ostream_iterator< std::string_view >{ std::cout, "\n" } );
}
```

This works with gcc 12.1 (compile with `-std=c++20`), but it doesn't work with clang 14.0.0 because clang hasn't implemented [P2210](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2210r2.html) yet.